# typescript export error :: Declaration or statement expected TS1128

Tags: reactjs, typescript, export

I'm in the process of enabling typescript to an existing React app at work and I keep getting this typescript export error when I start up the dev server.

```
TypeScript error in /App/some-path-at-work/index.js(2,1):
Declaration or statement expected.  TS1128

export something from './something'
```

It only gets resolved when I refactor to

`export {default as something} from './something'`

1. Is there a way to resolve this without me having to go through EVERY file in the app? This is a massive app.
2. Could someone explain why typescript is complaining in the first place? I did some research but I still could not fully grasp why this error is thrown.

Comment: I don’t think this is specifically a TypeScript issue, I’d recommend reviewing the documentation on exports https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky but everything works correctly when typescript is not enabled